# anyone used any idea for capturing captcha in selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

anyone used any idea for capturing captcha in selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As below, the two are mutually exclusive. If Selenium could simulate a captcha, then it would allow robots to override the captcha mechanism (which is meant to exclude robots).

Two ways I've used:

Have a switch in the code to disallow captcha for Selenium testing.

Automate the rest of the test and enter the captcha manually - good article [here](http://stevebywater.blogspot.com/2008/01/selenium-and-captcha.html) using the "break" command.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of captcha is that it shouldn't be doable by an application.

So you either

- need a "back door" to your  captcha provider that can tell the test application what to enter, or
- need to mock your captcha provider to return well-known values
- need to configure your application to not actually test the entered values and pass the test anyway.